# como puedo crear textarea required y readonly

Tags: textarea, required, readonly

Buenas tardes comunidad como puedo hacer que un campo texarea sea
required y readonly
ya que si ingreso los dos no toma en cuanta uno
`

`
esto solo funciona en la laptop y en celular me deja escribir datos campo tex

Comment: Son condiciones excluyentes entre si. No es posible hacer eso.
 Si es required, significa que DEBE INGRESARSE algo, es decir debe tener un VALUE. SI es readonly, significa que NO es editable y por tanto si hay valores tienen que ser puestos programáticamente y no ingresados manualmente.

Comment: mando el dato programable

Comment: Publica el fuente, es posible que no se esté cumpliendo una condición, o bien que la ejecución de JavaScript sea inadecuada.